# How can I install pyautogui on vscode

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I have tried to install pyautogui on vscode by using the command 'pip install pyautogui' in the terminal and it and it said `Successfully installed PyTweening-1.0.4 mouseinfo-0.1.3 pyautogui-0.9.53 pygetwindow-0.0.9 pymsgbox-1.0.9 pyperclip-1.8.2 pyrect-0.2.0 pyscreeze-0.1.28`
but when I try to import it into the code vscode tells me that the library is not installed here is a screenshot for demonstration[image]

how can I solve this problem and install pyautogui properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559

what you have to do is pretty simple

```
pip install pyautogui --use-pep517
```

it should work

[image]